# Is any Language better than PHP for Web Development?

Tags: php

PHP has Thousands of Functions related to Web Development baked right in from Simple Ones like `filter_var()` , `htmlentities()` to `json_encode()` `similar_text()` and `levenshtein()` distance for Percentage matching. There are so many `array()` and `string()` functions that it is really mind-blowing !

Now comes complete OOP support in PHP5 and Native Unicode in  PHP6.

Because try writing for example a Cookie in Java or a Servlet and you know what I am talking about. For String and Array handling most probably I am inventing some for-loop Algorithm in Java when in PHP I always find some ready-made function. Recent examples for me have been `array_count_values()` [Nothing similar in Java for finding aggregate of a Cart] and `array_chunk()` [ Try wrestling with Java Tokenizers here] . `similar_text()` Function in PHP is itself a beauty when you need to find How much 2 Strings matcheach other percentage-wise.

Does any other Web Development Language has such Vastness and Sheer Expanse as PHP ?

Comment: All of them. :-)

Comment: I think PHP rocks,  but this isn't a question for SO.

Comment: @Paul, def agree, PHP has to be one of the worst

Comment: You say 'Thousands of Functions' as if that is a good thing.

Comment: Those functions whose absence in Java you bemoan are probably available in 3rd party libraries (I would guess that probably many are in Apache Commons). The only difference there compared to PHP is that with PHP, those functions are part of the default install, but if you're *really* serious about building a web app, would you really throw up your hands and cry that the Java base install doesn't have the functions you want, or would you go out and find them? The functions aren't a part of the language. Just libraries.

Answer (score 7):

**There is no language better than another.**

There is one language which fits your application requirements and knowledge better, and that's the one you should choose.

Comment: have to disagree, there are languages better than others, (why wouldn't there be?) and php is far down this list IMO

Comment: @Rick: If PHP fits your functional requirements and meets your needs, it's a good language. ASP.NET gives you as much opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot than PHP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302933/asp-net-vs-php-performance-future-proofing-ease-of-development/2303675#2303675

Comment: People always say no language is better than another, but this seems pretty obviously false — or would you consider writing a Web app in Unlambda?

Comment: Chuck, don't give me any ideas.

Comment: @Chuck: you could write a webapp even in Malbolge (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge) if you are comfortable with it and it fit your needs... its more probably that you make mistakes if you use a language, could even be the best one, that you dont know.

Comment: If it fits your application requirements, +1 for that.  PHP is widely used given it is free other then hardware / server bandwidth. Which is why many people use it. It all boils down to application requirements, which include budget.

Comment: @Chuck: Like I said... A language is only good when it fits your requirements... Obviously, Unlambda doesn't fit...